# php remove characters from beginning to a selected character

Tags: php, string, strip

I want to know is there is anything available in PHP to remove 437800__ From  437800__611.

Original:
437800__611

What i want to end up with:
611

Basically need to start from the beginning of the string, and stop just after __ to keep 611.

Comment: if that is the entirety of the string... `preg_replace('/^([^_]*_+)/','', $myVar);`  or if all numeric, `preg_replace('/^(\d+)_+/','', $myVar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `substr($str, strpos($str, '__') + 2)`. This will find the first occurrence of '__' (two consecutive underscores) and remove everything before the '__' including the underscores themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
<?php


 $string = "437800__611";
 $result = preg_split("/^\d+__/", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

 // The $result would be...
 array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "611" }
```